# How can I convert text to DateTime?

Tags: python, datetime, raspberry-pi

I scraped a website and got the following Output:

```
2018-06-07T12:22:00+0200

2018-06-07T12:53:00+0200

2018-06-07T13:22:00+0200
```

Is there a way I can take the first one and convert it into a DateTime value?

Comment: what you mean by datetime value, just change the type or entire format ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: `import dateparser` and `dateparser.parse(<dateString>)` should be working for those examples.

Comment: There are parser functions for this purpose. GIYF: https://www.google.fr/search?client=ms-android-sonymobile&ei=8IRgW5-GOIqMlwSpkY2QAg&q=Python+datetime+from+string&oq=Python+datetime+from+string&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.12..0l4j0i22i30.2359.24980..26245...0.0...1862.20290.4-3j4j9j5j2......0....1.......3..41j46j0i131.NCfqtVeZx8I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `string` format of `datetime` to `datetime` **object** like this using `strptime`, here `%z` is the ***time zone*** :

```
import datetime
dt = "2018-06-07T12:22:00+0200"
ndt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

# output 
2018-06-07 12:22:00+02:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Just parse the string into year, month, day, hour and minute integers and then create a new date time object with those variables.

Check out the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

Answer (score 0):

The following function (not mine) should help you with what you want:

```
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%Y%V')
```

You can mess around with the [keys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) next to the % symbols to achieve what you want. You may, however, need to do some light cleaning of your values before you can use them with this function, i.e. replacing 2018-06-07T12:22:00+0200 with 2018-06-07 12:22.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime lib.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

`datetime.strptime` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

[Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/948445)